# How do populate gridview itemtemplate from stored procedure

Tags: asp.net, ado.net

How would you populate the gridview itemtemplate textbox using a drop down box to toggle the data from a stored procedure?

Comment: Well, so far I have a script that takes the value from the textbox in the gridview and passes it to a parameter stored procedures that inserts. But what if I wanted to populate some of the columns using a stored procedure?

Answer (score 0):

Why not have the drop down's value be what you want it to be when selecting the item? Why make a call to the DB to get this?